# How to pass table as a parameter to stored procedure - CosmosDB

Tags: sql-server, azure-cosmosdb

currently we are using a web application that passes Table as a parameter to the stored procedure.

The application frontend is ASP.NET MVC and backend is SQL Server.

In our application, we create a dataset in C# and pass it as a parameter to the procedure. 
With the help of UDT (User Defined Table), where received data in stored procedure and carry out our further processing.

I am not able to find facility to create and manage UDTs on Azure CosmosDB.

Is it possible to implement the same in Azure CosmosDB? If not, is there any alternative where I can pass data to the procedure without UDT?

Comment: Why you need to pass table as parameter into stored procedure? You want to process data then persist them in cosmos db?

Comment: So that we can update/insert multiple records of/into the tables.

Comment: Do you know Azure Data Factory, it could do data process and transfer for you.

Comment: Actually we have our own logics which we code in stored procedures. In our application, the user makes some changes in the values on screen, and entire data on screen is sent to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB does not support UDT's. You can use it as a document template.

You will need to serialize the dataset in order to insert it.